# TestCafe is losing control over popup-window during login process

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, e2e-testing, testcafe

Currently I am working on some e2e Tests for my angular project. I am facing the issue that TestCafe doesn't take the control over the new popup-window after a click on the login button.
Is there a way to take control over the new popup-window manually?

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture`Getting Started`
  .page`localhost:4200`

const signInButton = Selector('#signInButton')
const userEmail = Selector('#textEmail')
const nextUserEmail = Selector('#nextEmailButton')
const userPassword = Selector('#textPassword')
const nextUserPassword = Selector('#nextPasswordButton')

test('Should login', async t => {
  await t 
    .click(signInButton)
    
  await t
    .typeText(userEmail, 'xy@mail')
    .click(nextUserEmail)

  await t
    .typetext(userPassword, 'pw')
    .click(nextUserPassword)
});
```

Thanks for any help and best regards

Comment: What TestCafe version are you using? What does the 'new popup window' look like? Could you please share your public web site URL or a simple sample illustrating this behavior? This will help us find a solution.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your fast reply. Currently I am using version 1.11.0. Unfortunately I am not able to share these information. I will try to describe it: After I press the login button, a pop up window appears. This website is form an external service, so I am restricted in changing something there. I can see the TestCafe overlay a few moments. Then the site reloads, I think it creates a session, and TestCafe loses the control and the TestCafe overlay disappears. Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: We need to review an example to determine the cause of the issue. If you can share one, please open [an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md) in the testcafe repository.